# Simple Scan : no scanners available, Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, scanner

I have two Ubuntu computers on the same network.
The old one uses Ubuntu 14.04. Simple scan works perfectly with my Samsung SCX-3205w.
The new one uses Ubuntu 15.04. On it, simple scan cannot find the same scanner : "No scanners available. Please connect a scanner".
I've tried to launch simple scanner as root without success.
The printing function works.

Do you have any advice ? Thanks.

Edit:

The connection is through wi-fi.

Following A.B. request, here is the output of sudo sane-find-scanner :

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x0a5c [Broadcom Corp], product=0x216f [BCM20702A0]) at libusb:001:003
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

and sane-find-scanner :

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8000 at 004:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8008 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0a5c/0x216f at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x06cb/0x2ac3 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x573c at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

thanks

Comment: Per USB or Ethernet?

Comment: Post the output of `sudo sane-find-scanner` and `sane-find-scanner` in your question. (The Ubuntu 15.04 machine). Your scanner has a "good" support: http://www.sane-project.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=Samsung&model=SCX-3205w&bus=any&v=&p=

Comment: Post the content of `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` (14.04 and 15.04) in your question. Are there differences? And give me a ping.

Comment: Maybe that helps further: http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html

Comment: Interesting, this is a Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth: `found USB scanner (vendor=0x0a5c [Broadcom Corp], product=0x216f [BCM20702A0]) at libusb:001:003`

Comment: Alright ! I installed the suld-driver-4.00.39 package as described in the link you provided, and that made the scan work instantly. Thanks a lot for your help and time A.B. ! If you want to answer the question, I can validate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a driver for your Samsung SCX-3205W

Open an terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samsungmfp-driver
```

More infos and software [here](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html).

Comment: I actually installed the "suld-driver-4.00.39" package. Thanks a lot.

Comment: samsungmfp-driver is a meta package

Comment: @Istopopoki No upvote for me? ;)

Comment: Here you go :) I didn't have enough reputation to upvote 1 hour ago...